# Need to Resolve: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I purchased a template from themeforest and am having a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of undefined" after I removed two of the three opening sliders.  The error slows the page load time down to a crawl however the entire site is functional.  Does 'each' reference the 3 original sliders and if so can I edit it to reference the 1 lone slider?

```
function init_main_slider(target) {
set_height();

jQuery(target).flexslider({
    animation : 'fade',
    controlNav : true,
    directionNav : true,
    animationLoop : true,
    slideshow : false,
    animationSpeed : 500,
    useCSS : true,
    start : function(slider) {
        if(!isMobile) {
            slider.slides.each(function(s) {
                jQuery(this).find('.animated_item').each(function(n) {
                    jQuery(this).addClass('animate_item' + n);
                });
            });
            slider.slides.eq(slider.currentSlide).find('.animated_item').each(function(n) {
                var show_animation = jQuery(this).attr('data-animation');
                jQuery(this).addClass(show_animation);
            });
        }
        else {
            slider.find('.counter').find('.num').each(function() {
                var container = jQuery(this);
                var num = container.attr('data-num');
                var content = container.attr('data-content');

                count_num(num, content, container, false);
            });
        }
    },
    before : function(slider) {
        if(!isMobile) {
            slider.slides.eq(slider.currentSlide).find('.animated_item').each(function(n) {
                var show_animation = jQuery(this).attr('data-animation');
                jQuery(this).removeClass(show_animation);
            });
            slider.slides.find('.animated_item').hide();

            var counter_block = slider.slides.eq(slider.currentSlide).find('.counter');
            if(counter_block.length > 0) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    counter_block.find('.num').each(function() {
                        jQuery(this).html('0');
                    });
                }, 300);
            }
        }
    },
    after : function(slider) {
        if(!isMobile) {
            slider.slides.find('.animated_item').show();

            slider.slides.eq(slider.currentSlide).find('.animated_item').each(function(n) {
                var show_animation = jQuery(this).attr('data-animation');
                jQuery(this).addClass(show_animation);
            });

            var counter_block = slider.slides.eq(slider.currentSlide).find('.counter');
            if(counter_block.length > 0) {
                counter_block.find('.num').each(function() {
                    var container = jQuery(this);
                    var num = container.attr('data-num');
                    var content = container.attr('data-content');

                    count_num(num, content, container, 1500);
                });
            }
        }
    }
});

function set_height() {
    var w_height = jQuery(window).height();
    jQuery(target).height(w_height).find('.slides > li').height(w_height);
}

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    set_height();
});
}
```

Comment: www.brandhouseindy.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you "remove the sliders"?  I noticed in the html that the slide still has a class of `<li class="slide_3">` which might be causing issues for the plugin.  Does it make a difference to remove that or change to just slide or slide_1?  If you cant get it to cooperate one idea is that there really is no need for this slider when only have one image so you could count the number of `<li>` and only use that function when there is more than one image, otherwise insert the single image... something like.

```
jQuery(function() {
  // count the list
  var listSize = $(".slides li").size();
  if (listSize < 2) { 
    $('#main_slider').prepend('<img src="images/pic_slider_1_3.png" alt="">')
  } else {
    init_main_slider('#main_slider');
  }
});
```

Comment: I updated my answer with some thoughts.. my guess is that there might be something else with how the page was edited that is breaking this slider.  I had a kind of hacky idea I posted as well.

Comment: The guys I'm editing this for like the possibility of adding additional slides later.  I tried changing the slide class to <li class="slide_1"> but it didn't yield any change in load time.  I think I'm going to go with your fix for the time being and revert when/if they want to add more.  Really appreciate it!